# Akka - convert Flow into Collection or Publisher

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I'm trying to split an Akka `Source` into two separate ones.

```scala
  val requestFlow = Flow[BodyPartEntity].to(Sink.seq) // convert to Seq[BodyPartEntity]
  val dataFlow    = Flow[BodyPartEntity].to(Sink.asPublisher(fanout = false)) // convert to Publisher[BodyPartEntity]

  implicit class EitherSourceExtension[L, R, Mat](source: Source[FormData.BodyPart, Mat]) {
    def partition(left: Sink[BodyPartEntity, NotUsed], right: Sink[BodyPartEntity, NotUsed]): Graph[ClosedShape, NotUsed] = {
      GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder =>
        import akka.stream.scaladsl.GraphDSL.Implicits._
        val partition = builder.add(Partition[FormData.BodyPart](2, element => if (element.getName == "request") 0 else 1))
        source ~> partition.in
        partition.out(0).map(_.getEntity) ~> left
        partition.out(1).map(_.getEntity) ~> right
        ClosedShape
      }
    }
  }
```

How to convert `requestFlow` into `Seq[BodyPartEntity]` and `dataFlow` into `Publisher[BodyPartEntity]`

Comment: As @LeviRamsey commented on my post, you can use `Broadcast` instead of `Partition`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [BroadcastHub](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-dynamic.html#using-the-broadcasthub) for this. From doc:

> A BroadcastHub can be used to consume elements from a common producer by a dynamic set of consumers.

Simplified code:

```
val runnableGraph: RunnableGraph[Source[Int, NotUsed]] =
  Source(1 to 5).toMat(
    BroadcastHub.sink(bufferSize = 4))(Keep.right)

val fromProducer: Source[Int, NotUsed] = runnableGraph.run()

// Process the messages from the producer in two independent consumers
fromProducer.runForeach(msg => println("consumer1: " + msg))
fromProducer.runForeach(msg => println("consumer2: " + msg))
```

Comment: Regular `Broadcast` would probably better fit than `BroadcastHub`, since the question doesn't seem to need the consumers to be dynamic.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I think I was trying to answer two posts with one answer. `BroadcastHub` gave a cleaner code for both, but they both only needed `Broadcast`. Thanks for noting.